# 2 Questions: 1. Why http api sometimes fail to load data from net ? 2. Flutter image taking too much space RenderFlex error

Tags: api, dart, http, flutter-layout, flutter-packages

I am new to flutter and stackOverFlow. I would be highly grateful for your help, or even a slightest idea.

Question 1st:
You can see in the pictures attached, that first two cards have successfully loaded the  rating (in green background). But in the 3rd and 4th card, it shows "444.1111". It is the default value, i gave statically. Why sometimes http works and sometimes fail to load data from  net ?

I am using HTTP flutter packge, and using get data using this function

```
static var client =    my_http_alias.Client() ;
 
  static Future<List<Welcome>> fetchProducts() async {
var response = await my_http_alias.get(Uri.parse('https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json?brand=maybelline'),);
if (response.statusCode == 200){

  var jsonString =  response.body;

  return welcomeFromJson ( jsonString ) ;
}
else{
  //error.
  return welcomeFromJson('name: Some thing Went Wrong' );
}
```

}

## =======================

I want my images to be displayed full, but when I try to do so (by wrapping with Expanded), it overflows the other widgets. I have tried many things, and came here in hope of finding answers.

The error code is:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 55 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///C:/Users/qurat/StudioProjects/getx_5_rest_api/lib/views/product_tile.dart:45:16
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#279b1 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: offset=Offset(8.0, 8.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=152.4, h=152.4)
...  size: Size(152.4, 152.4)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: start
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 55 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///C:/Users/qurat/StudioProjects/getx_5_rest_api/lib/views/product_tile.dart:45:16
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#522a9 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: offset=Offset(8.0, 8.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=152.4, h=152.4)
...  size: Size(152.4, 152.4)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: start
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 55 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///C:/Users/qurat/StudioProjects/getx_5_rest_api/lib/views/product_tile.dart:45:16
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#064bd OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: offset=Offset(8.0, 8.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=152.4, h=152.4)
...  size: Size(152.4, 152.4)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: start
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================
Reloaded 1 of 758 libraries in 1,709ms.
D/EGL_emulation( 5457): app_time_stats: avg=120567.27ms min=120567.27ms max=120567.27ms count=1
```

---

My full code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_types.dart';
import 'package:getx_5_rest_api/models/product.dart';
import 'package:getx_5_rest_api/models/product.dart';
import 'package:getx_5_rest_api/models/product.dart';
import 'package:getx_5_rest_api/models/product.dart';
import 'package:getx_5_rest_api/models/product.dart';
import 'package:getx_5_rest_api/models/product.dart';


bool isFavorite = false;
void invertFav() {
  if (isFavorite == false) {
    isFavorite = true;
  } else {
    if (isFavorite == true) {
      isFavorite = false;
    }
  }
}



// final Welcome welcomeObj =  Welcome(name: 'd-default', price: 'd-default', imageLink: 'd-default', rating: 9000.9000 );

class ProductTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Welcome welcomeObj;
  const ProductTile(this.welcomeObj);

  @override
  State<ProductTile> createState() => _ProductTileState();

}

class _ProductTileState extends State<ProductTile> {
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Card(
      elevation: 2,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    // height: 180,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                    ),
                    child: ClipRect(
                      child: Image.asset(
                       'assets/image.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: 0,
                    child: Obx(() => CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: widget.welcomeObj.isFavorite.value
                            ? Icon(Icons.favorite_rounded)
                            : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                        onPressed: () {
                          widget.welcomeObj.isFavorite.toggle();
                        },
                      ),
                    )),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                widget.welcomeObj.name,
                maxLines: 2,
                style:
                TextStyle(fontFamily: 'avenir', fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            if (widget.welcomeObj.rating != null)
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(-1,0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4,  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.welcomeObj.rating.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.star,
                        size: 12,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text('\$${widget.welcomeObj.price}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, fontFamily: 'avenir')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: What i want image to look like:]

[image: What i want other widget below that image, to look like:]

Comment: image loading problem, please edit the reference image url

Comment: now i have used Images from local asset .
it should load, but the main problem is still there, the picture is 'half-shown'